# How to make angular js hide DOM elements, and not remove them, in filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular ng-repeat with filter works this way (I just discovered it by observing DOM in Chrome's developer tools):

It actually removes the nodes which don't satisfy filter condition and re-renders everything.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OmidShariati/NAumK/15/) example. If you look at the DOM, and see what happens there, you can understand what I mean.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Instant Search</h2>
  <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="state in states | filter:filterText">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.abbreviation">
            {{state.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need now, is to make angular js hide nodes, not remove them. In other words, when I filter nodes, for example I want to make those nodes which don't satisfy filter condition to have a class of `hidden`, and I'll hide them via CSS.

Answer (score 4):

ng-show placed on the repeating element will cause them to be hidden: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NAumK/19/

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="state in states" ng-show="state.name.indexOf(filterText) != -1">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.abbreviation">
            {{state.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" ng-model="textFilter" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Filters remove elements as does the `ng-if` and `ng-switch` directives.  You can also use css coupled with the `ng-class` directive to hide the elements however I recommend sticking with the `ng-show` for clarity.  One further note of caution, hiding as opposed to removing elements makes the test cases harder to prove.  You can have collisions with classes that display incorrectly but still pass (Selenium) tests.

Comment: thanks Emmentaler I just update code. 
I dont really know why the downvote for this good answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `filter` in `ng-repeat` because it filters the actual array that `ng-repeat` receives. You'll have to implement your own "filtering" logic.

I'd do it using a conditional `ng-class`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3bp6r/):

```
<li ng-repeat="state in states" ng-class="{'hidden': isHidden(state)}">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.abbreviation">
        {{state.name}}
    </label>
</li>

$scope.isHidden = function(state) {
    if(state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.filterText.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thinks that one answer would be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/OmidShariati/NAumK/25/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Instance Search</h2>
  <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="state in states" 
          ng-show="state.name.tolowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase()) != -1">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="state.selected">
            {{state.name}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `filter` on `ng-repeat` is case insensitive, your code breaks that. Also it does not add a `hidden` class, it uses `display: none;`.

Comment: by adding a toLowerCase() first issue resolved and. do you have any soloution for second issur?

Comment: Yes, use `ng-class`, as I specified in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` instead of filters.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace filter with:

```
ng-show="([state] | filter:filterText).length > 0"
```